# How to upload file on server using php

Tags: php, upload

Im using php code to upload a file.
The problem is i can only code it to upload file on my local host.
How do I code the target directory that can upload file in server using info such as localhost, name, password etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a remote file transfer such as `ftp`.

Taken from the PHP manual:

```
<?php 
$ftp_server=""; 
$ftp_user_name=""; 
$ftp_user_pass=""; 
$file = "";//tobe uploaded 
$remote_file = ""; 

// set up basic connection 
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 

// login with username and password 
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// upload a file 
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) { 
    echo "successfully uploaded $file\n"; 
    exit; 
} else { 
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n"; 
    exit; 
    } 
// close the connection 
ftp_close($conn_id); 
?>
```

Comment: can the file type be an audio file like `caf` in this line `if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII))`?

Comment: It transfers binary data. File format doesn't matter.